# `DesignMode` in subcontrols is not set correctly?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

I have a compound control contains nested controls. The problem i am facing is that control read properties from a global setting class which is static and intern read from setting file. To stop individual control from accessing configuration in design mode i added check in each control.

```
If(!DesignMode){
    ...
    //Initialize properties e.g. prop = AppConfig.GetProperty("prop1");
}
```

The problem is that individual control work fine when open in VS. But when i open top control containing nested control i get error by VS designer. The error is that in a nested control `DesignMode=false` for some reason.

I also created a test app and created a simple control within another control to test if there is a problem with VS but it seem to work correctly for any depth of controls.

I dont even know how to debug this. For now i comment out the property initializing code and build it and then open designer and there uncomment it and build it again to run it.

Did anyone came across this problem or is there any way to fix it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that the DesignMode is **not set** while in Constructor (at any level).

Move your initialization methods to Load event, to avoid this problem.

Also, you could add additional comparison with:

```
 protected bool IsInDesignMode
 {
    get
    {
        return DesignMode || LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;
    }
 }
```

This would definitely provide an acurate way to determine the design mode because sometimes VisualStudio 
returns DesignMode = false while you're placing user controls on the form, or refreshing the form display itself in design.

Comment: code in constructor is the problem. I have moved them to OnLoad() and added property you provided in base control class as double check. Its now working thanks.

Comment: I've just tested that (VS2012): Both above suggested tests return `false` when evaluated inside `OnLoad()` method of nested control during design time. Finally, inserting the `LicenseManager` condition into [Control extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/447319/Resolve-DesignMode-for-a-user-control) seems to be a 100% functioning approach.

Answer (score 1):

i do define static bool NotInDesignMode in Program.cs and set it to true in Main()

that way i dont take any dependencies on LicenseManager.UsageMode

however you wouldnt do that if you are writing a generic class lib.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem.
Maybe this will help you.

```
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (Application.ExecutablePath.IndexOf("devenv.exe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0)
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_NormalImage != null) m_NormalImage.Dispose();
                if (m_DownImage != null) m_DownImage.Dispose();
                if (m_HoverImage != null) m_HoverImage.Dispose();

                m_NormalImage = null;
                m_DownImage = null;
                m_HoverImage = null;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }

        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
```

Comment: I think that the use of "DesignMode || LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime" would be a better solution (and it works fine for me). That's because it is not sure that Microsoft will still call the IDE "denvenv.exe" in future (they could change and this code could not work). At the same time is not sure that all developers use Visual Studio, someone might use Sharp Develop or Xamarin Studio, for example...

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the problem that the `DesignMode` flag was set **after** the `Load` EventHandler has been invoked. I solved this by writing this extension method which checks if the parent control DesignMode flag has been set.

```cs
public static bool InDesignModeSelfOrAncestors(this Control control) {
  static bool GetDesignModePropertyValue(Control c) {
    if (c.GetType().GetProperty("DesignMode", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic) is {} property) {
      return (bool) property.GetValue(c, null);
    }

    return false;
  }

  var designModeFlag = GetDesignModePropertyValue(control);
  while (control.Parent is {} parent) {
    control = parent;
    designModeFlag |= GetDesignModePropertyValue(control);
  }

  return designModeFlag;
}
```